# Как сделать снимок системы на Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Надо сделать снапшот системы. Имею Убунту сервер и локальную сеть. Подскажите, с чего начать. Если можно - как это сделать попроще.

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов достаточно [много](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem).

Если нужно удаленно подключаться к Ubuntu-серверу и делать снимки, то подойдет rsync

```
sudo rsync --delete -az -e ssh /home/path/source/ user@host:/home/path/target
```

В результате выполнения команды удаленная папка target будет содержать копию папки source. Разумно скрипт выполняющий бэкап поместить в крон, тогда синхронизация будет проходить периодически. Более продвинутой "версией" rsync является rsnapshot: там уже многое сделано за нас. Пример использования: [настройка резервного копирования в Ubuntu](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/linux/45912/).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Clonezilla тебе поможет http://www.clonezilla.org/